# Some files not showing up in DIR command

Tags: command-line

After a mostly successful drive recovery, there are many strange new files with filenames like:

[ªí_SJ._s

_îsŠ0DÞo.QAJ

Ç%_n)412.00

These files are huge, multi-gigabyte. I'm deleting them. But it would go faster if I could know where they all are in the folder tree and go directly to them.

So I opened a command prompt window (this is in Windows 10) and ran this command:

DIR /S > Dir.txt

The result was normal except that the files with the strange filenames are not included.

Any suggestions on how I can get a file list including subfolders that includes the files with those strange filenames?

UPDATE:

Adding parameters /as or /ah in case the files have system or hidden attributes results in "File Not Found".

UPDATE 2:

The characters in these filenames are not unicode nor high ASCII. For the first one listed above, these are the ASCII codes in the filename:

91

170

237

95

83

74

46

95

115

UPDATE 3:

Okay this is weird:

I inadvertently closed the CMD window so opened it again and found that now the files were listed in DIR. So I tried to remember all the things I'd done to isolate what had made the difference, and then tested each of them separately. Here's what I found:

In File Explorer, if I select the file and press F2 to go into edit mode on the filename, then just press Escape to exit edit mode, then close the CMD window and open a new CMD window...that's what it takes for the file to be listed in DIR.

But it only fixes the problem for that folder; not any of the others.

Any idea how I can make that happen for all folders?

Comment: Try DIR /ah and DIR /as both to see if the parameters reveal the files you are looking for.

Comment: @John Thanks but the result is File Not Found in both cases.

Comment: I recommend disclosing the secret file system.

Comment: At a guess, those "files" may be corrupted/unrecoverable junk. I have had similar experiences with bad (USB) drives where these types of "huge, funny name" files are just garbage, cannot be gotten rid of in many instances and (ultimately) indicators of hardware problems with the (USB) drive itself. If you can delete them, that's good, but my inclination would be to suggest that you rescue what you can and consider getting a new drive.

Comment: @Anaksunaman  Yes, I'm assuming these files are junk. I'm deleting them.

Previously for several days I'd had permissions weirdness on the drive that wasn't resolved by taking ownership of everything. So I moved everything over to another drive, removed the partition on the problem drive, and started over. No more permissions problems and no problem deleting  these files. What I'm trying to do with this Dir output is to find the problem files more quickly.